# Rust unwrapping a file object in a streamlined way

Tags: file, rust, unwrap

I am using this code. It compiles and works ok, i really have an issue with this line
**self.fd.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(content.as_bytes())** is there a better way of extracting the File object from a Option without having to do as_ref().unwrap() every time? I feel like rust is such a feature packed language it must have a better way of doing this than what im using.

```
use std::path::Path;                    
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::{Write,Read};                             
                                    
struct rustfile{
   filename: String,
   fd: Option<File>,
}
                                            
impl rustfile{       
                                  
    fn new(filename: &str)->Self{
         rustfile{    
             filename: filename.to_string(),
             fd: None,                   
         }                                
     }                    
                           
    fn exists(&self) -> bool{     
        Path::new(&self.filename).exists()
    }
                                                                                            
    fn write(&mut self, content: &str){
        //check if file exists.
        if !Path::new(&self.filename).exists(){
            //Does not exist. 
           self.fd =Some(OpenOptions::new()
           .append(true)
           .create(true)
           .open(&self.filename)
           .expect("Error opening file"));   
           self.fd.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(content.as_bytes())
           .expect("Error writing to file.");
        }
         else{                                                                                    
             self.fd = Some(OpenOptions::new()
             .append(true)
             .open(&self.filename).expect("Error opening file"));
             self.fd.as_ref().unwrap().write_all(content.as_bytes())
             .expect("Error writing to file i opened");
         }                                                                                           
     }      
 }                            
                                           
            
 fn main() {
     let mut rf = rustfile::new("blah.txt");
     rf.write("Test,lets see if this works");                     
 }
```

Comment: Since you are setting the field to `Some` just before, you could use [`Option::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.insert) to get a reference back instantly

Comment: I don't see why you are storing the `fd` as an `Option<File>`, maybe you are using it later? Anyway it looks like you are shying away from local variables: if you write `let fd; if blah { fd = ...; } else { fd = ...; } self.fd = Some(fd);` you avoid your main issue, I think.

Comment: Note that if you call `write` multiple times, it will close the file and reopen it each time. Is that really what you want? Moreover it will keep the file open after the first `write` call and close and reopen immediately on the second call. Wouldn't it make more sense to close the file immediately in the first call if you really want this close-reopen cycle?

Comment: This is the one issue i have with rust i dont know how to keep a type in an struct. Since nothing can be set to Null for example if i am not assigning the fd right away i have to make it an option and set it to none.  uneless there is a better way that im missing.. also to the bottom point, if write closes and opens the file anyway does that mean there is no benefit to storing the fd as opposed to just the filename? anyway the problem still exists for eg if i want a struct to hold a TcpStream or some other type etc that i dont want to set right away

Comment: I meant _your_ `write` function closes and reopens the file. It is absolutely possible to write code that keeps the file open and just reuses it: simply check if `self.fd.is_none()` so that you won't reopen the file if it is already opened.

Comment: Although in your place, I would probably get rid of the `Option` and just open the file in the constructor.